# python jira cannot transition issue

Tags: python, linux, jira

I am using the python jira module
https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#transitions

```
def jira_comment():
    options = {
        'server': 'https://xxxxxxxxx.atlassian.net'}

    jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('xxxxx', 'xxxxx'))

    jira_commit = get_github_ticket("https://github.com/xyz/project-1/commit/99c8d17aa7eb33643881cd47e70c0892607e9caa")
    jira_ticket = jira_commit[1].split(" ")[0].replace("#","")
    issue = jira.issue(jira_ticket)

    jira.add_comment(issue, 'test by KSHK #4=')

    transitions = jira.transitions(issue)
    for t in transitions:
        print (t['id'])
        print (t['name'])

    jira.transition_issue(issue, '261')

def main():
    jira_comment()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However it cannot transistion the issue, the user has admin access already.

**OUTPUT**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pyhunt2/github_test.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pyhunt2/github_test.py", line 71, in main
    jira_comment()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pyhunt2/github_test.py", line 46, in jira_comment
    jira.transition_issue(issue, '261')
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pyhunt2/jira/client.py", line 108, in wrapper
    result = func(*arg_list, **kwargs)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pyhunt2/jira/client.py", line 1255, in transition_issue
    url, data=json.dumps(data))
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pyhunt2/jira/resilientsession.py", line 153, in post
    return self.__verb('POST', url, **kwargs)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pyhunt2/jira/resilientsession.py", line 146, in __verb
    raise_on_error(response, verb=verb, **kwargs)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pyhunt2/jira/resilientsession.py", line 56, in raise_on_error
    r.status_code, error, r.url, request=request, response=r, **kwargs)
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://xxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/SBAU-11601/transitions
    text: Can't move (SBAU-11601). You might not have permission, or the issue is missing required information. If you keep having this problem, contact your Jira Administrator.

    response headers = {'X-Seraph-LoginReason': 'OK', 'Connection': 'close', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'X-AUSERNAME': 'xxxxx', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Server': 'Atlassian Proxy/0.1.131', 'ATL-vTM-Backend-Time': '991', 'X-AREQUESTID': '528x869535x11', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=315360000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'ATL-vTM-Queue-Time': '0', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform', 'Date': 'Wed, 11 Oct 2017 08:48:46 GMT', 'ATL-vTM-Time': '991'}
    response text = {"errorMessages":["Can't move (SBAU-11601). You might not have permission, or the issue is missing required information. If you keep having this problem, contact your Jira Administrator."],"errors":{}}
```

Comment: Is the transition you want to set in your workflow?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things which i understood from you error log:

1. Do you have access to perform transition on this issue actually? Just go to your jira server and check whether can you manually perform the transition on the issue or not?
2. Is the "Id" you are specifying for transition is the same transition id according to your jira workflow? You must send jira transition id and not the actual transition name that results after performing transition.